# Getting a Clean Sound with a Vox VT20

Tags: amplifiers

I've bought a Vox VT20 and while it's great, I'm having a hard time trying to get the cleanest sound possible. So far, I've found that the only way to do this is by turning on the tuner, but having the tuner on is really annoying while you are playing. **What's the right setup to turn all effects off?**
I've tried going to manual mode and the selecting the clean amp, setting value and depth to off, but I still notice some echo or reverb is added.

I checked the users manual, but I can't find the setup needed in order to get a clean sound.

Comment: Is it fair to assume that you have tried turning off all the effects including the reverb? I.E. the value knob is turned to the off position, the depth knob is turned to the off position, and the reverb knob is turned to the off position. Just so we're not giving answers to something you may have already tried. I am assuming your working with this interface: http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/musical-instruments/detail-page/sc_b004jlx7b0-06top_lg.jpg

Answer (score 1):

After trying the clean amp model, try lowering the Volume and Gain knobs a lot (as in less than a quarter turn even), and then just increasing the Master Volume. You may have to increase the Master Volume knob a lot since those other knobs are very low.

Always start from a low volume increasing slowly while giving your guitar a few strums to make sure that the amp doesn't turn out to be exceedingly loud after fiddling with the settings.

It's also possible that your guitar has a very high output, so it may help to lower the volume knob on your instrument as well to maybe half or less.